# Multer upload files into array of objects

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, multer

I have an array of objects like this:

```
data: [
    {"image": File, "certificate": File},
    {"image": File, "certificate": File}
]
```

The way I'm taking to read the files on the server is doing a loop before send the POST request:

```
...
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', data[0].image);
fd.append('image', data[1].image);
fd.append('certificate', data[0].certificate);
fd.append('certificate', data[1].certificate);
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', fd, options);
```

Then on the server side I do:

```
upload.fields([{ name: 'image', maxCount: 2 }, { name: 'certificate', maxCount: 2 }])
```

So my question is... Is there a way that if I send the array like:

```
fd.append('data', data)
```

so multer can take the files that are into the data field?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't, I think is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, this is what worked for me

Backend Code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, './images/'))
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + file.originalname)
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post('/generate', upload.fields([{ name: 'layer1', maxCount: 6 }, { name: 'layer2', maxCount: 6 }, { name: 'layer3', maxCount: 6 }]), function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.files)
})
```

Client request:

```
    const formdata = new FormData();
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");

    for (const layer of layers) {
        for (const img of layer.files)
            formdata.append(`layer${layer.id}`, img)
    }
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/generate", requestOptions)
```